# Android - long ellipsed textview cover next textview

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have list view. Row has 2 (and more in future) text views. My goal is that if first text is too long, then ellipse should be shown, but second text view should be always visible. I temporary solved this by columns (weightsum + percentage weight on text views). But my goal is: when text is short, then second text view should appear right next to the first (see first attached screen, it is fake - created by hard coded maxwidth for first text view). Problem is that when first text is too long, then second text just disappear. I have tried many configuration with linearlayout, relativelayout, sublayouts etc. but finally I stuck. Any idea? This is simple xml for row:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Some very very long long long long long long long"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#C03518"
        android:text="10"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is code with relativelayout which doesn't work too:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"           
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some very very long long long long long long long"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/TextView01"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#C03518"
        android:text="10"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Target]

[image: Reality]

Regards

Comment: Try relative layout and android:layout_toRightOf="idOftheLeftTextView"
it will possibly ellipsize it for you !

Comment: I agree with the commenter above, but this approach requires the second TextView have `layout_alignParentRight="true"`.

Comment: I tried with RelativeLayout too, but same result. I edited first post with relativelayout example. Maybe can I calculate this in runtime? For example calculate width of second text and then set is as distinction in maxwidth of first text

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a custom flow layout like this:
http://karimvarela.com/2012/12/01/android-creating-a-flowlayout/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a weight for the columns. Something like this :

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Some very very long long long long long long long"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#C03518"
    android:text="10"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This would mean that the first column would take up 90% of the screen and the second would take up 10%.
Alternatively you could use a table layout and set the stretch_columns to 0,1.
Something like :

```
<TableLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:stretch_columns="0,1" >

<TableRow>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/TextView01"
android:layout_width="0"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="9"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="Some very very long long long long long long long"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/TextView02"
android:layout_width="0"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="#C03518"
android:text="10"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```